# Room. Добавление в избранное. Ошибка при вызове update

Tags: android, android-room

Помогите понять, что не так делаю. Есть список айтемов во фрагменте. При клике открывается фрагмент с его полным описанием и там есть кнопка "добавить в избранные". При попытке вызвать update `model.update(data);` кидает ошибку

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void avocado.droid.ptitsami.room.DataDao.update(avocado.droid.ptitsami.room.Data)' on a null object reference
    at avocado.droid.ptitsami.room.DataRepository$updateAsyncTask.doInBackground(DataRepository.java:54)
    at avocado.droid.ptitsami.room.DataRepository$updateAsyncTask.doInBackground(DataRepository.java:44)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)`
```

Но model не равно null. В методе onChanged данные успешно устанавливаются.

DataDao

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE id = :id")
LiveData<Data> getById(int id);

@Update
void update(Data data);
```

DataRepository

```
  LiveData<Data> getById(int id) {
    return db.getDatabase().dataDao().getById(id);
}

void update(Data data) {
    new updateAsyncTask(dataDao).execute(data);
}

private static class updateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Data, Void, Void> {

    private DataDao mAsyncTaskDao;

    updateAsyncTask(DataDao dao) {
        mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Data... params) {
        mAsyncTaskDao.update(params[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
   public class DataViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    LiveData<Data> currentData;
    DataRepository repository;


    public DataViewModel(@NonNull Application application, final int dataId) {
        super(application);
        int verseId = dataId;
        repository = new DataRepository(application);
        currentData = repository.getById(verseId);
    }

    public LiveData<Data> getById() {
        return currentData;
    }

   public void update(Data data) {
        repository.update(data);
    }


    public static class ModelFactory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {

        @NonNull
        private final Application application;
        private final int dataId;
        private final DataRepository repository;

        public ModelFactory(@NonNull Application application, int id) {
            super();
            this.application = application;
            this.dataId = id;
            repository = new DataRepository(application);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
            if (modelClass == DataViewModel.class) {
                return (T) new DataViewModel(application, dataId);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

и метод фрагмента, где все происходит

```
final DataViewModel.ModelFactory factory = new DataViewModel.ModelFactory(
            getActivity().getApplication(), getArguments().getInt(KEY_DATA_ID));

    final DataViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)
            .get(DataViewModel.class);

    model.getById().observe(this, new Observer<Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(final Data data) {
            tvTitle.setText(data.getTitle());

            favorite = data.getFavorite();
            if (favorite == 0) {
                ivLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_outline);
            } else {
                ivLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_ok);
            }

            ivLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (favorite == 0) {
                        favorite = 1;

                        model.update(data); 
                        ivLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_ok);
                        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.my_anim);
                        ivLike.startAnimation(anim);

                    } else {

                    }
```

Comment: DataDao равно null. В Вашем репозитории есть поле dataDao проверьте его, когда вызываете asynctask

Comment: Спасибо большое! Глупая ошибка